# How to get the ok button in element-plus daterange datePicker

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, element-plus

I have a requirement of having ok button in element-plus daterange datePicker. i am getting it for datetimerange picker.But need it in daterange picker too.

How Can I get it. Please help me in this.

This is what I want to implement : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er6b7.png)